# Father of us all?

Tags: riddle

His brothers will always help you,
Slaying spiders or golems.
Sometimes you see him for real,
Depending on how you live.
And the thing you won't believe,
Is that he can melt steel.
Even if he looks like a gem,
One day he will crush you.

Who is "he"?

hint 1 (kinda big one) :

> He will crush what is left of you, if there is something left by that time!

hint 2  :

> Line three is more of a joke than a real sentence and may concern Stack users :)

hint 3 :

> the two first lines refer to a video game

last hint :

> A very famous guy died trying to reach it

Comment: Any possible answer that comes to mind gets rejected because of that damn title...

Comment: The title is more like a mini hint, not a restriction

Comment: jet fuel doesn't look anything like a gem

Comment: But jet full can't melt steel beams :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could the answer be :

> The sun

His brothers will always help you,
Slaying spiders or golems.

> See comments

Sometimes you see him for real,
Depending on how you live.

> If it's about people on Stack, I guess it means that since you spend all your time on your computer, you don't see the sun often

And the thing you won't believe,
Is that he can melt steel.

> Sun generates heat which can melt anything

Even if he looks like a gem,
One day he will crush you.

> The sun is sometimes referred to as a gem. And when it will explode it will crush our while solar system.

Hint 1 :

> He will crush what is left of you, if there is something left by that time! 
>  The sun will not explode for another 6 billions year I think

Last hint :

> A very famous guy died trying to reach it
>  This could refer to Icarus who died for getting to close to the sun, melting his wings.

Comment: Congrats, you got it right ! the first two lines refer to dark Souls, a quite popular video game

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Who are the Sun's brother in DS who help you?

Comment: the convenant of the sun. Player joining this covenant can help other players in the story by beeing summoned. They are refered as SunBros, which stand for sun Brothers. This also created a somehow popular meme called "praise the sun"  :)

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Thanks for the explaination! Nice riddle btw :D

Answer (score 2):

> Coal?

Not sure about the first two though.

Sometimes you seem him for real depending on how you live.

> Suggests difference between classes maybe. Upper class living on electricity lower struggling for heating

and the thing you won't believe is that he can melt steel

> Fairly obvious. Used for furnaces and could be made to forge steel

even if he looks like a gem

> Apply enough pressure and you get a diamond

one day he will crush you

> After death, fossilised and turn to coal yourself under the pressure

Comment: Please use spoliers: >!

Comment: Sorry, the result fits the two first lines, good try though :)

Answer (score -1):

air or water...

oxygen can melt you and iron in time if there is humidity (water) in the air, air has water so it can kill spiders as well.

Golems are made of clay so you may slay it with water (which is the brother of air?)

Comment: it doesn't fit enough lines i'm sorry mate